# How to get UserName in Facebook API ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4

i'm using Facebook native API for sharing in my iPhone App, i need to know as soon as user logged in i need his username, how can i get this?
Any help is appriciated in advance.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate one.refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170735/how-to-retrieve-facebook-response-using-facebook-iphone-sdk/5195951#5195951

Answer (score 2):

You can use Graph API to do this. Just make a request in fbDidLogin delegate method:

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {    

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];    
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];  

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath: @"me" andDelegate: self];      
}
```

And then you can get all the information about current user in didLoad method:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoadRawResponse:(NSData*)data
{
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", response);
        [response release];
}

- (void) request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result
{        
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {                   
        NSString *name = [result objectForKey: @"name"];
        NSString *fbID = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
    }
}
```